# What functions to put inside a class

Tags: class, language-agnostic, function, encapsulation

If I have a function (say `messUp` that does not need to access any private variables of a class (say `room`), should I write the function inside the class like `room.messUp()` or outside of it like `messUp(room)`? It seems the second version reads better to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tradeoff involved here. Using a member function lets you:

- Override the implementation in derived classes, so that messing up a kitchen could involve trashing the cupboards even if no cupboards are available in a generic room.
- Decide that you need to access private variables later on, without having to refactor all the code that uses the function.
- Make the function part of an interface, so that a piece of code may require that its argument be mess-up-able.

Using an external function lets you:

- Make that function generic, so that you may apply it to rooms, warehouses and oil rigs equally (if they provide the member functions required for messing up).
- Keep the class signature small, so that creating mock versions for unit testing (or different implementations) becomes easier.
- Change the class implementation without having to *examine* the code for that function.

There's no real way to have your cake and eat it too, so you have to make choices. A common OO decision is to make everything a method (unless clearly idiotic) and sacrifice the three latter points, but that doesn't mean you should do it in all situations.

Answer (score 2):

Any behaviour of a class of objects should be written as an instance method.

So `room.messUp()` is the OO way to do this.

Whether `messUp` has to access any private members of the class or not, is irrelevant, the fact that it's a behaviour of the room, suggests that it's an instance method, as would be `cleanUp` or `paint`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring which language, I think my first question is if messUp is related to any other functions. If you have a group of related functions, I would tend to stick them in a class.

If they don't access any class variables then you can make them static. This way, they can be called without needing to create an instance of the class.

Beyond that, I would look to the language. In some languages, every function must be a method of some class.

In the end, I don't think it makes a big difference. OOP is simply a way to help organize your application's data and logic. If you embrace it, then you would choose room.messUp() over messUp(room).

Comment: -1 for "If you embrace it" ... if you are using an OO language it  should be mandatory in any professional environment to use it as it was intended,  not down to the whim of the individual.  This is how we end up with coding horrors.

Comment: If you read his comment, you'd see he didn't say he was using an OO language. He was just asking which is better, whatever that means. Moreover, languages like C++ routinely have functions that are not class members. And being a Nazi about the approach people take to development serves no objective purpose whatsoever. So that's two wrong for you...

Comment: @Jonathan, -1 for Godwins law, as well as missing key words used in the OP's question. ... "access any private variables of a class" what non OO language uses private variables in a class? (or even has classes?!? the mind boggles.) - Now, I won't disagree that there are often good uses/reasons for  functions in even an OO system that act in the way that `messup(room)` would act, however... 1. Because it seems to read better to me; 2. because I feel like it, are not good reasons. But worse still is 3. Because I don't want to embrace encapsulation in an OO language.

Comment: @Slomojo: VB6 had classes but did not officially qualify as an OO language. At any rate, it appears you're on a little bit of a mission to impose your ideas on others, so I'll stop here. Carry on...

Comment: @Johnathan... OOP and encapsulation aren't my ideas.

Comment: In this specific context, encapsulation is what should be encouraged, or transcended, perhaps a `new messUp()` strategy for the room would be a good idea, since different ways of messing up rooms would be useful.  This isn't about pushing an idea, it's about saying that even though *freestyling* is cool in some contexts, **generally** in programming and systems design it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

i base myself on ["C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, And Best Practices"](http://www.amazon.fr/Coding-Standards-Rules-Guidelines-Practices/dp/0321113586) by Sutter and Alexandrescu, and also Bob Martin's SOLID. I agree with them on this point of course ;-).

If the message/function doesnt interract so much with your class, you should make it a standard ordinary function taking your class object as argument.

You should not polute your class with behaviours that are not intimately related to it.
This is to repect the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle): Your class should remain simple, aiming at the most precise goal.

However, if you think your message/function is intimately related to your object guts, then you should include it as a member function of your class.